# How to download a list of files in background without affecting the performance of other activities?

Tags: java, android

My application starts with a request to the server to get a list of urls. I want to download all these files(html,css and js files) from the urls. But I want these downloads to happen in the background without interfering with the performance of other activities.

I had an approach of making a Volley Request with an AsyncTask inside onResponse().

But Android is been throwing me warning like "Too much work happening in MainActivity"

Comment: By download do you mean download and save to file system or download just to render it to the user in an app environment?

Comment: Yes, by downloading I mean saving to the filesystem.

Comment: Oh, wait i've a perfect solution..

Answer (score 1):

You Should definitely try Async Task for the same

```
public class Sample extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample);
        new BackGroundTask().execute();  

    }


class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
            super.onPreExecute();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
            {
               //method 
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! But I did the same too. But I get the URLs from an endpoint using Volley Request(as mentioned in the question). This greatly affects the performance of my other requests.

Comment: Yes Use Volley/Retrofit , with Async, works like charm

Answer (score 0):

Since downloading it to a filesystem is what you're looking for and also need it to happen completely in background, you can try the `DownloadManager` system service:

The code for which looks like:

```
 DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Request pdfDownloadRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(
                    /*url endpoint here*/));
            pdfDownloadRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            pdfDownloadRequest.setDescription("Can add custom description here.. ");
            pdfDownloadRequest.setTitle("This sets a title for the download foreground notification");
            pdfDownloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            pdfDownloadRequest.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);

          // once the request is set, just add it to the download manager and it will handle it for you.. 
            downloadManager.enqueue(pdfDownloadRequest);
```

`DownloadManager` is a foreground system service, check the doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)

Also as you can see in my code, i've used it to download a PDF file, you can use this system service to download files as heavy as an entire movie :)